# Angular Primeng Charts: Bar Chart with Line Chart

Tags: angular, bar-chart, primeng

Please help. Has anyone here already implemented this type of chart combination in angular2+? Im currently using angular 6.

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/combo-bar-line.html

Please share your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <p-chart type="bar" [data]=monthlyConfig></p-chart>
```

and you need to pass a type parameter to the config.

```
    this.monthlyConfig = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: '#FF671F',
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: Array.from({ length: 6 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
    }, 
    {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      backgroundColor: '#FF671F',
      data: Array.from({ length: 6 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)),
      borderColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: 2
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following angular charts** :
https://canvasjs.com/angular-charts/

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as CanvasJS from './CanvasJS';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})     
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "light2",
        animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: "Monthly Expense"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            toolTipContent: "<b>{name}</b>: ${y} (#percent%)",
            indexLabel: "{name} - #percent%",
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 450, name: "Food" },
                { y: 120, name: "Insurance" },
                { y: 300, name: "Traveling" },
                { y: 800, name: "Housing" },
                { y: 150, name: "Education" },
                { y: 150, name: "Shopping"},
                { y: 250, name: "Others" }
            ]
        }]
    });

    chart.render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I was able to get help with the ff answer from another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571243/extend-bar-chart-on-chart-js-2-into-a-new-type-of-chart#answer-39870718 chartjs already supports bar chart with line chart by adding another data points and specifying the type "line: on the additional line chart data set.

Comment: can i have two chart in the same row ?